# What filter is this?

Tags: control-engineering, aerospace-engineering, simulation, servo

I am implementing a second order filter.
It simulates hydraulic servo on an airplane. Its about 35-40 years old.

[image: Second order filter to simulate servo]

What confuses me is the notation. Like "2(.7)(52)S", what does it mean? If its just products, why then not write the resulting number?

I tried with doing 2704/(S^2+72.8S+2704), but it seem a bit slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be written that way because the [transfer function](http://www.kves.uniza.sk/kvesnew/dokumenty/DREP/Filters/2nd%20order%20transfer%20function.pdf) of a second order system is written as:

$$
h(s) = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2}
$$

where $\zeta$ is the relative damping ratio and $\omega_n$ is the natural frequency.

So in your system

\begin{align}
\zeta &= 0.7 \\
\omega_n &= 52
\end{align}

It's easy to see what the parameters are when it's written with $\zeta$ and $\omega_n$ factored out.